# How to redirect an url in codeigniter so it will omit a subfolder?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I would like to redirect `www.mydomain.com/sub_folder/controller` to 
`www.mydomain.com/controller`.

I've installed CodeIgniter at `www.mydomain.com/sub_folder/`, and I'm using the following code in my `.htaccess` file in the root directory:

```
RewriteRule ^/sub_folder/controller/?$ ^/controller/?$
```

Comment: what is the difference between both the url?

Comment: sorry nish here is the correct one ..redirect "www.mydomain.com/sub_folder/controller" to "www.mydomain.com/controller" ,

Comment: If the Codeigniter is installed in www.mydomain.com/sub_folder/ at-least need to keep the index.php file in the root and the application path has to be updated inside the index.php to executed something in the subfolder after the redirection. After that you can try updating the .htaccess file to hide the index.php

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule doesn't match leading slash so try following:

```
RewriteRule ^sub_folder/(controller)/?$ /$1/ [L,NC]
```